# equals methods not working in java. HW

Tags: java, methods, equals

I have two equals methods in code, yet neither of them work. I made one myself and then I also auto generated one from Eclipse via source. I've run the program multiple times with one or an other and again, neither work.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.math.*;
public class Item {
     static //the properties of an Item
     double cash=59;
     static double sum=0;
    private int priority;
    private String name;
    private double price;




    //default constructer
    public Item() {
        priority = -1;   //fill with default values
        price = 0.0;
        name = "No name yet";
    }


    public Item(int priority, String name, double price) {//constructor with all 3 arguments 
        this.priority = priority; 
        this.name = name;         
        this.price = price;
    }


    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        //priority must be between 1 and 7
        if (priority > 0 && priority <= 7) {

            this.priority = priority;
        } else {
            //otherwise default to 0
            System.err.println("Error, enter 1 through 7"); 
            //this.priority = 0;
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        //would I put equals method here. name.equals.name?

        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;

    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {

        //price between 0 and 100 inclusive
        if (price >= 0.00) {
            if (price <= 100.00) {
                this.price = price;
                cash = cash-=price;
                sum=sum+=price;

            } else {

                System.err.println("Error: price to high");
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("Error: price to low");
        }
    }


    public boolean equals(Item otherItem){
        if(this.getPriority()==otherItem.getPriority());
            System.err.println("Error, Same Priorities detected");
            return true;





     }






    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + priority;
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Item)) {
            return false;
        }
        Item other = (Item) obj;
        if (priority != other.priority) {
            return false;
        }
        System.err.println("Error, Same Priorities detected");
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Item [Price=").append(getPrice()).append(", ");
        if (getName() != null) {
            builder.append("Name=").append(getName()).append(", ");
        }
        builder.append("Priority=").append(getPriority()).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }





    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Item[] list = new Item[2];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 1; i <= list.length; i++) {

            if(cash==59)
            {
                System.out.println("You have 59 dollars");
            }


            Item anItem = new Item(); // new item object created 7 times

            System.out.println("Enter an item you want to add to your list " + i);
            anItem.setName(keyboard.next());

            System.out.println("Enter a price " + i);
            anItem.setPrice(keyboard.nextDouble());

            System.out.println("Enter the priority of the item " + i);
            anItem.setPriority(keyboard.nextInt());


            list[i-1] = anItem;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
            System.out.println("Cash left "+cash);
            System.out.println("Sum of Items "+sum); 





      if(sum>59)
     {System.out.println("Error, you ran out of money");

     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));}

        }

    System.out.println( list[1].getPriority());


    }




    }
```

Comment: Remove the `equals()` method you have added.

Comment: Always use `@Override` annotation for your override methods. Your equals method is wrong, is not a true method override, and if you use the annotation, the compiler will then tell you. Note that you use an incorrect method parameter.

Comment: Where do you call the `equals()` methods? it seems me your not using them.

Answer (score 5):

This method here is completely biting you in the a**

```
public boolean equals(Item otherItem){
    if(this.getPriority()==otherItem.getPriority());
        System.err.println("Error, Same Priorities detected");
        return true;
}
```

First, there's an `;` after the `if`'s condition so it's not doing anything and therefore your method is always returning `true`.

Second, this method overloads the `equals(Object)` method that you should be overriding and using. Get rid of it.

When overriding methods, annotate them with `@Override`. With an IDE that will do a check and validate that you are actually trying to override a method.

Comment: sry, typo. I was deleting stuff and accidentally left ;.

Comment: @user2803251 In that case, only the `System.err.println()` will be part of the `if` block. It will still always return `true`.